# Downloading Progrees hud hides on scrolling in uitableview cell

Tags: ios

cell for row atindexPath delegate code:

```
        if ([[[chatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"chat_type"] isEqualToString:@"2"])//video
        {

            UIImageView *bg = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

            UIImageView* chatImg = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

            UIButton* playBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

            DACircularProgressView* progress1;

            [bg setTag:-705];

            [chatImg setTag:-704];

            [playBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(playVideo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            UIImage *bubble;

            CGRect bgRect;

            if([[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"logindata"] objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:[[chatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"user_id"]]==YES)
            {
                [bg setFrame:CGRectMake(112, 12, 200, 106)];

                [chatImg setFrame:CGRectMake(124, 21, 172, 86)];

                [playBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(149.0, 25, 119.0, 74.0)];

                bubble = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"recieverImg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24 topCapHeight:15];

                bgRect = CGRectMake(8.0, 11.0, 200, 106);

                progress1= [[DACircularProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(188.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)];
            }
            else
            {
                [bg setFrame:CGRectMake(8, 12, 200, 106)];

                [chatImg setFrame:CGRectMake(25, 21, 172, 86)];

                [playBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(54.0, 25, 119.0, 74.0)];

                bubble = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"senderImg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24 topCapHeight:15];

                bgRect = CGRectMake(108.0, 9.0, 200, 106);

                progress1 = [[DACircularProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(94.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)];
            }

            //ProgressView
            [progress1 setTag:-707];

            progress1.roundedCorners = YES;

            if([dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"download_%@",[[chatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"audio_chat"]]]!=nil && ![[dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"download_%@",[[chatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"audio_chat"]]] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && [[dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"download_%@",[[chatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"audio_chat"]]] length]>0)
            {
                [progress1 setHidden:NO];
            }
            else
            {
                [progress1 setHidden:YES];
            }

            ///////////////////////////

            bg.image = bubble;

            CALayer * l = [chatImg layer];

            [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
            [l setCornerRadius:5.0];

            // You can even add a border
            [l setBorderWidth:4.0];

            [l setBorderColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];

            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[chatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"audio_chat"]]];

            if ([appDel isFilePresent:filePath])
            {
                // Use to show the video is downloaded
                [playBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

                UIImage *thumbnail = [self thumbnailFromVideoAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];

                chatImg.image=thumbnail;// whichever imageview you want give this image

                [playBtn setSelected:YES];
            }
            else
            {
                chatImg.image =UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad?[UIImage imageNamed:@"Big.png"]:[UIImage imageNamed:@"small.png"];
                // Use this to show download image
                [playBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"download.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                [playBtn setSelected:NO];
            }


            [cell.contentView addSubview:bg];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:chatImg];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:playBtn];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:progress1];

        }

---------
-(IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender
{
 if (!isPresent)
    {
        isuploading = YES;

        if (isdownloading)
        {
            isdownloading=NO;

            DACircularProgressView* progrees1 = (DACircularProgressView *)[cell viewWithTag:-707];

            [progrees1 setHidden:NO];

            progrees1.trackTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200.0/255.0 green:200.0/255.0 blue:200.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

            progrees1.progressTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

            [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"yes"] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"download_%@",[[chatArray objectAtIndex:clickedButtonIndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"audio_chat"]]];

            [appDel startDownloadFile:[[chatArray objectAtIndex:clickedButtonIndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"audio_chat"] inPath:filePath withRefrence:self];

        }
        else
        {
            [appDel showToastWithText:@"Error!!" detailText:@"Downloading is in progress..." viewController:self];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No one is going to read the code and try to understand your problem. Add some description. :)

Comment: I am using DACircularProgressView class for showing progress of downloading in UItableview cell its working fine and i have also implemented paging concept(10 msg per page).
the Problem arises when i scroll table and service fire for 2nd page that time progress view gets hide and downloading is in progress.

So how can i stop this hiding???
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not going to read all that which is not complete anyway but maybe you shouldn't dequeue the cell, you should create another one or save the state of the cell so you could add the HUD progress to it.

The reason is that the live cells in the memory are only the ones visible to the user, so when the user scrolls and the cell disappears, it'll be killed and removed from memory.